# ViewBag doesn't refreshed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the controller I have some value that changs every 10 seconds, I'm passing this value to ViewBag. the problem is that the value at the view doesnt change never, it shows only the first value when page load.

Here my code:

```
public class LonLat
{
    public int Lon { get; set; }
    public int Lat { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult DrawPath()
{
   ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
   Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "5");
   SetTimer();
   lonLat = new LonLat
   {
       Lon = 200,
       Lat = 100
   };
   ViewBag.Message = lonLat;
   return View();
 }

private void SetTimer()
{
  aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);           
  aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
  aTimer.AutoReset = true;
  aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   lonLat.Lon = new Random().Next(-180, 180);
   lonLat.Lat = new Random().Next(-90, 90);
   ViewBag.Message = lonLat;           
}
```

And in view:

```
@{
    var data = ViewBag.Message;
}

<h3>RecordName: @data.Lon</h3>
<h3>RecordDetail: @data.Lat</h3>
```

But I alawaws see the value 200 and 100, how to make the ViewBag to be refreshed?

I tried to add `Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "5");`

Comment: Because whenever you refresh the page it assigns the variable with default values `lonLat = new LonLat
   {
       Lon = 200,
       Lat = 100
   };`

Comment: @AliBahrami You are right, thanks

Comment: If you define your `lonLat` field static in your controller, and only assigning default value only if it's null your workaround might work. What you are doing isn't a best practice  ( using a thread for a long-running job in aspnet)